# Algorithm/iterative procedure for constructing hypercyclic vectors?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, banach-spaces, constructive-mathematics

Let $B$ be a separable Banach space and let $L:B\rightarrow B$ be a hypercyclic operator; here I use the definition of hypercyclicity given implicitly by Birkhoff's Transitivity Theorem: *continuous linear operator for which every two distinct non-empty open subsets $U$ and $V$ there is some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $L^N(U)\cap V \neq \emptyset$*.

Also, let $b \in B$ be given and be such that $L^n(b)\neq L^m(b)$ for any $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n\neq m$.

Is there an iterative procedure/algorithm for constructing a sequence $\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, using only $b$, $L$, and the vector space structure on $B$ such that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_n$ converges in $B$ to a hypercyclic vector?  I'm looking especially for something constructive.

Some special cases of such constructions are:

- [Chaos on function spaces](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/4F5119DAEFF883E15D0F145EB354AAC2/S0004972700038417a.pdf/chaos_on_function_spaces.pdf)
- [Explicit constructions of dense common hypercyclic subspaces](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Eprims/pdf/43-2/43-2-17.pdf)

Are there other known procedures or broader (constructive/algorithmic) methods?

Comment: Definitely some of them but usually not all of them. In what particular terms do you want us to describe them? I mean, take the usual example of twice the backward shift in $\ell^2$. What answer do you expect here?

Comment: Another "what can be said" question ... these are not very satisfying.

Comment: @NikWeaver I made the question much more precise now.  I'm looking for an algorithm to construct a hypercylic vector.

Comment: @fedja I was mostly looking for a way to construct them, beginning from a reasonable starting point in $B$.

Comment: You probably should make your question more precise in a constructive sense. In constructive math, the statement "$L$ is a hypercyclic operator" *should* be equivalent to having an explicit construction of a hypercyclic vector, because existence implies explicit constructibility. This renders your question difficult to answer in a meaningful way. For example, a more meaningful constructive question would be: `Is there a constructive proof of Kitai's Criterion?'.

Comment: @FrankaWaaldijk But is Kitai's Criterion necessary and sufficient, I think there are examples of hypercyclic operators which do not satify it?

Comment: Sure, but one step at a time is already quite a constructive pace in this area! The second cited paper above actually shows (I believe...) how to prove constructively that an infinite dimensional Banach space with basis admitting a weighted backward shift, is hypercyclic. Any other constructive criterions for hypercyclicity would be most welcome, even if they are not exhaustive. It does not seem likely that you will find an exhaustive criterion, as long as there is no such thing even in classical mathematics...

Comment: Fair, I guess what I'm trying to ask is if there is a constructive version of the second paper's result when the space doesn't necessarily admit a generalized weighted-backshift operator

Comment: OK that's maybe helpful... but do you know the answer in the classical case? Is it true that any continuous linear $L$ on a Banach space with a Schauder basis is hypercyclic classically, when given a ${b}$ such as you describe? If that is not the case, or if we don't know, then one needs to know some explicit criterion beforehand (different from "$L$ is hypercyclic" since that implies that you already have your hypercyclic vector).

Comment: Actually, we don't need to have it explicitly before hand since by 'L is hypercylic' I mean L is continuous, linear, and topologically transitive (then we know such a vector exists by Birkhoff but it doesn't mean I have it).  (This is in the classical case since Birkhoff uses Baire so it is non-constructive).

Comment: Then please define 'topologically transitive' constructively in your question, because the most common definition I see is again one where an explicit existence of a dense trajectory is used... It may seem a bit like nit-picking, but really it isn't, because in order to have an algorithm, one must know the given data quite precisely.

Comment: @FrankaWaaldijk Yes you're right, I make the updated.

Comment: Let's constructivize a bit more. In the first paragraph, you should say "inhabited" instead of "non-empty" and "$L^N(U) \cap V$ is inhabited" instead of $L^N(U) \cap V \neq \emptyset$." I also worry about "distinct $U$ and $V$", should that be just "$U \cap V = \emptyset$" or something stronger, such as $\forall x \in U, y \in V, \|x - y\| > 0$?

Comment: Similarly, we can consider strenghening $L^n(B) \neq L^m(b)$ to $\| L^n(b) - L^m(b) \| > 0$.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I'm not sure I see why we should use the condition $\|x-y\|>0$, what is the intuition/motivation?

Comment: In construcive mathematics it often makes sense to use an [apartness relation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/apartness+relation) instead of inequality. In a normed space that would be $\| x - y \| > 0$. For instance, if you know $x \neq 0$ you cannot yet normalize $x$ to $x / \| x \|$, but if you know $\| x \| > 0$ then you can.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know this.  I'll make the update shortly.  Thanks for the insight!